# Using state value to filter API fetch result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I am using a fetch request to get some FX rates from an API. However, I only need to store the rate for a currency that's been previously selected by the user and saved as state (`state.currency`).

The example below works well for predefined values (e.g. json.rates.**GBP**) but I can't find a way to link it with `this.state.currency`.

Here is my current code:

```js
var fxRates;

class FxRateCheck extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currency: "",
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    fetch("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        fxRates = json.rates.GBP;
        // I need to replace GBP with the value of this.state.currency
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false
        });
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user sets the currency base in their state, you then need to use the same value as the key when you access a property in a different object.

```
fxRates = json.rates[this.state.currency];
```

There are a few other things you need to change though. the global variable `fxRates` is generally a bad practice, if you need to use the result in other places in your component consider putting it on the component state.

You should also let the user choose what to compare with. `?base=USD` is hardcoded currently. Maybe consider letting them change that in a future change :)

[**Heres an example of what I was describing :)**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-kare-j4b9t?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you, I was so close all this time :) Initially, I was using a separate state to hold the fxRate but I've read that it's not the best practice to address a state from another state. As for the currency, the hardcoded value was just present a working code, now that the issue is fixed, everything is nicely customizable :)

Comment: Happy to help! I made a customizable solution in the link I posted if you want to check it out for a more working solution :D let me know if you have any issues :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dot and bracket notation to access properties in an object

```
const data = {
  id: 1,
  value: "one"
}
```

can be accessed like

```
  data.value
```

or

```
  data["value"]
```

or

```
  var property = "value";
  data[property]
```

So, in your case you can do it like

```
  fxRates = json.rates[this.state.currency];
```